# Uninstalling application (with Alternate Entry Point for synchronization) from device

Tags: blackberry, synchronization, blackberry-jde

I have added to the project Alternate Entry Point with argument "init", "auto-run on startup" and "do not display on homescreen" checkboxes checked, so that application could be backed-up and restored. And now I can't delete it from my device... It doesn't appear on Desktop Manager as well. 
Please advice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen that before... Have you tried removing it with [javaloader](http://www.enduserguides.com/mobile/blackberry/eug_bbjavaloader.html)? Use the *-u erase -f* followed by your cod file name to force remove it.

Comment: have not tried before, but have tried it now - it is working and it is great :) thanks a lot! And how can it be done by simple user? :) I mean the one who can't use comand line tools?

Comment: I know it sounds odd but try reversing it - have the main Application set as "auto-run on startup" and "do not display on homescreen", have the alternate entry point with the icon and pass in argument like "gui" and run it in reverse (run the gui with the argument). That's how I ended up setting it... :)

Comment: thank you very much, it realy helped. Is it possible to give you some points? :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped! You already gave me points with marking my answer as the solution and voting up my answer  :)

Comment: @Tamar: Can you please tell me why such behavior is there (I mean why these apps can't be deleted)?

Comment: @Mudassir: I have no idea, to me it seems like a bug... You'll have to ask someone at rim  :)

Comment: Thanks the `-f` was the bit I was missing. Full command `javaloader erase -f <application name>`